# Combine cells in the first row

Tags: r, dataframe, union

can somebody help me?

This is my actual data_frame

[image: This is my actual data_frame]

and this is what I'd want to get

[image: and this is what I'd want to get]

Is there a way to combine only the cells in the first row in R?

I was trying to do it in excel one by one but I've more than 6000 columns so it takes me ages!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I guess this is not possible, because each column in a `data.frame` needs to have a unique name in order to distinguish between column p and column x, wherein p ≠ x. Suppose you have four columns A-D. If you collapse the names of A+B and C+D, then change the respective names of the first and third column to AB and CD and set nothing (`''`) as names of the second and fourth column, `R` will not be able to distinguish between the second and fourth column when you call to the second column with `df[, '']`.

Comment: It depends on what your purpose is. Could you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: That was because I had items with two values for each position. But now I've decided to solve the problem changing the table format.

Thank you, for help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Dion Groothof mentioned in the comments, you can't merge two cells in R data frames, but if your desire is to merge cells in an excel worksheet you can use the `openxlsx` package:

```
library(openxlsx)

> df
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  var1  var2 
  <chr> <chr>
1 A     B   
2 1     2    
3 3     4    
4 5     6  

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet1")
df[1,] <- paste(df[1,], collapse = "")
writeData(wb, "Sheet1", df)
mergeCells(wb, "Sheet1", cols = (1:2), rows = 2)
saveWorkbook(wb , "E:/test1.xlsx", overwrite = T)
```

the result would be:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could collapse all the cells in the fist row into one cell and leave the others empty. If x is your data frame:

```
x[1,] <- c(paste(x[1,], collapse=""), rep("", ncol(x)-1))
```